unittest class init mock exception raised
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = None
        self.__authorised_users = ["me", "you"]
        local_input = input("please provide your windows 8 character lower case login: ")
        if local_input not in self.__authorised_users:
            raise ValueError("you have no permission to run this app")
        else:
            self.__name = local_input

class TestUser(unittest.TestCase):
    def testUserClassFound(self):
        self.assertNotIsInstance(ModuleNotFoundError, User)
    @patch('builtins.input', lambda *args:"y")
    def testUserClassInit(self): # just check if user class has __name set to none
        local_object = User()
        self.assertEqual(local_object._User__name, None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
    

I would like to, in the second test, just assure when the class object is created, the tester checks the class has the attribute __name and set to None.  I need to patch the raise ValueError from the class init , but I can't find the correct patch.

You can patch User.__init__ with a wrapper that suppresses ValueError:
def ignore(func, exception):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except exception:
            pass
    return wrapper

class TestUser(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.input', lambda *args:"y")
    @patch.object(User, '__init__', ignore(User.__init__, ValueError))
    def testUserClassInit(self):
        local_object = User()
        self.assertEqual(local_object._User__name, None)

Demo: https://ideone.com/TEpHsF

Did you try the demo? Please compare your code with the demo to see what may be missing in your code.

works perfect, but where do you get this info, I have looked for days to try and find this answer, read docs and manuals, only to have to ask SO finding out I would have never found this in the first place

You're welcome. This is just coding, piecing together with the end goal in mind relevant language features, each of which you can find documentation and tutorials for.
